# How to copy files from Liberty on Bluemix to Windows?

Tags: ssh, ibm-cloud

I'm using Windows7, I have cf setup, my app has been migrated to Diego and I can ssh into my app (cf ssh APPNAME). I can run scp within my ssh but I don't know what options to use.

From what I can tell, scp expects the target machine to have ssh running. So if I was connnected to Bluemix from a Linux box, the target would be my local box and a user that had ssh access. Since I'm running windows, that's not available by default.

If all of that is true, then I think I have a few options:
- use Linux instead
- install ssh into windows 
- possibly use something like winscp but I'm not sure if bluemix can only be accessed via the 'cf ssh' command

thoughts/ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to use something like WinSCP to transfer files.  You'll need to get a few things using the CF CLI first.

1. get the app guid from the command (where `<app_name>` represents the name of your app):
   `cf app <app_name> --guid`
2. get a one-time ssh code:
   `cf ssh-code`

Next, find the appropriate endpoint for your Bluemix region:

1. ssh.ng.bluemix.net:2222 for US South
2. ssh.eu-gb.bluemix.net:2222 for United Kingdom
3. ssh.au-syd.bluemix.net:2222 for Sydney

In WinSCP (or similar tool), use SCP file protocol, set the username to `cf:<guid>/<app_instance>` where `<guid>` is the guid from the above commands and `<app_instance>` is the instance number of your app (0 if your app only has one instance).  Set the host/port according to the host/port shown above for your Bluemix region, and set the password to your ssh-code from the `cf ssh-code` command.

You will then be able to login, remember that the ssh-code is one-time use so you'll need to regenerate that part every time you connect.

Comment: just adding-up, since using a client like WinSCP doesn't work quite nicely due to the one-time password... to download from command line you can use sftp like this `ex:
sftp -oPort=2222 "cf:a8e2d87f-3f1e-4ef5-80cd-342s1ae37a79/0"@ssh.ng.bluemix.net:/home/vcap/app/filename /tmp/filename`
`