# Not able to download Bluemix app source using bx cf download command

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am trying to download my app source developed on IBM Bluemix using `bx cf download` command, but I am simply getting a message saying `Files downloaded: 0/`

Here's the command I am giving
[image]

Here's my app listed 
[image]

The command creates a folder named Bluemix in C:\Bluemix directory, but it's empty.

Info -

It is a Node JS based app using Watson Conversation API.

Can any one help me resolve the issue?

Comment: How did you initially create this application?

Comment: If you never uploaded the code, then you can't download it.  So @Ram Vannam's question is important - How DID you create this application?

Comment: Yes. I uploaded the code manually. But have lost the code now.

Comment: please copy and paste cmd.exe output. Not screenshot.

Comment: Does a bx cf files show anything in your app?

Comment: commands are not valid anymore... you can remove this question and try with latest bluemix cli.

Comment: I'm not understanding the downvotes. The screenshots are mildly irritating, but otherwise I think this Q is reasonable and possibly useful to others. Unless you know something about the DEA-Diego migration, the problem is not obvious or easy to find info on.

Answer (score 0):

The `cf download` hasn't been viable since the architecture moved to [Diego](https://github.com/ibmjstart/cf-download/issues/12).  If it's just a couple of files,  you can take advantage of `bx cf ssh` and use cat like:

`bx cf ssh "myApp" -c "/bin/cat /home/vcap/app/mongostorage.js" > mongostorage.js`

But to get them all, the easiest way to achieve this is to go to your Bluemix dashboard and in your app, bottom right, add continuous delivery.  That will give you a Git repo you can `git clone` from and look at online.  This is best if you intend on doing any edits.

It is also possible to get them all using ssh.  See [How to copy files from Liberty on Bluemix to Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41858496/how-to-copy-files-from-liberty-on-bluemix-to-windows)